# Strange character in file breaks for loop silently

Tags: python

I'm parsing a file with python and the for loop breaks on 
character that in Notepad++ looks like this

```
©SUB0
```

my loop is simple

```
for line in open('myfile.dat').readlines():
    print line  
    print x
    x+=1
```

There is no error, the py file just quits.

What should i do to make it skip that character?

Comment: Is the file a binary file?  If so, you could try doing `open('myfile.dat', 'rb')` to open as binary.

Comment: How are you running your python file? Are you double clicking on it in Windows Explorer, or using the command line?

Comment: @BrenBarn, that was it, thank you :). Please post it as answer so i could accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the file a binary file? If so, you could try doing `open('myfile.dat', 'rb')` to open as binary.  If you open as text, an end-of-file character can cause it to stop reading prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the character you are encountering is a [substitute character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character).
This character substitutes a character that just cannot be read or printed on your device (whatever that means in your case).

Its representation are 26(ASCII), SUB, 0x1a(hex) and ^Z.

This is not Pythons fault, as every programming language would break here. Its a historical flaw and can only be avoided by not using it in a file.

As the user [BrenBarn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427416/brenbarn) suggests, try parsing it as binary file if possible.